# How do i navigate to new pages using my bottom-navigation-bar?

Tags: flutter, dart, routes, flutter-bottomnavigation

I want to navigate to new pages using the bottom navigation bar. What are the possible ways to navigate to new pages using the bottom navigation bar with the code i have attached below.

And in addition, i do not want the Bottom Navigation Bar in my new pages. I only want the bottom navigation bar in the current page.

Thank you in advance.

Code :

```
class dashboard extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _dashboardState createState() => _dashboardState();
}

// ignore: camel_case_types
class _dashboardState extends State<dashboard> {
  int currentIndex = 1;

  changeIndex(index) {
    setState(() {
      currentIndex = index;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final authService = Provider.of<AuthService>(context);
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 80.0, right: 250),
              child: Center(
                child: Container(
                  width: 200.0,
                  height: 20.0,
                  decoration:
                      BoxDecoration(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0)),
                  child: (const Text(
                    'Hello',
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.black),
                  )),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 300.0, top: 1.0),
              child: IconButton(
                icon: new Icon(Icons.account_circle, size: 30.0),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => Notifications(),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 300.0, top: 5.0),
              child: IconButton(
                icon: const Icon(
                  Icons.notifications,
                  size: 25.0,
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => Notifications(),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 0.0),
              child: Center(
                child: Container(
                  width: 390,
                  height: 450,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.green.shade100,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(onPressed: () async {
        await authService.signOut();
      }),
      //  : _children[_currentIndex],
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        backgroundColor: Colors.green[100],
        items: const [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.book_online),
            label: 'Page 1',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.read_more),
            label: 'Page 2',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.account_circle),
            label: 'Profile',
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can use onTap property**

```
onTap: _onItemTapped,

 void _onItemTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
    });
  }
```

*See the full code*

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class dashboadrState extends StatefulWidget {
  const dashboadrState({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<dashboadrState> createState() => _dashboadrStateState();
}

class _dashboadrStateState extends State<dashboadrState> {
  void _onItemTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
    });
  }

  int _selectedIndex = 0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 80.0, right: 250),
              child: Center(
                child: Container(
                  width: 200.0,
                  height: 20.0,
                  decoration:
                      BoxDecoration(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0)),
                  child: (const Text(
                    'Hello',
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.black),
                  )),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 300.0, top: 1.0),
              child: IconButton(
                icon: new Icon(Icons.account_circle, size: 30.0),
                onPressed: () {
                  print("hit");
                  // Navigator.push(
                  //   context,
                  //   MaterialPageRoute(
                  //     builder: (context) => Notifications(),
                  //   ),
                  // );
                },
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 300.0, top: 5.0),
              child: IconButton(
                icon: const Icon(
                  Icons.notifications,
                  size: 25.0,
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  print("hit ");
                  // Navigator.push(
                  //   context,
                  //   MaterialPageRoute(
                  //     builder: (context) => Notifications(),
                  //   ),
                  // );
                },
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 0.0),
              child: Center(
                child: Container(
                  width: 390,
                  height: 450,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.green.shade100,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(onPressed: () async {
        // await authService.signOut();
      }),
      //  : _children[_currentIndex],
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        backgroundColor: Colors.green[100],
        items: const [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.book_online),
            label: 'Page 1',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.read_more),
            label: 'Page 2',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.account_circle),
            label: 'Profile',
          ),
        ],
        currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
        selectedItemColor: Colors.amber[800],
        onTap: _onItemTapped,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Output**

[image]

**Updated Answer ( screen changing dynamically as you need )**

**Code:-**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class dashboadrState extends StatefulWidget {
  const dashboadrState({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<dashboadrState> createState() => _dashboadrStateState();
}

class _dashboadrStateState extends State<dashboadrState> {
  void _onItemTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
    });
  }

  int _selectedIndex = 0;
  static final List<Widget> _widgetOptions = <Widget>[
    Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 80.0, right: 250),
              child: Center(
                child: Container(
                  width: 200.0,
                  height: 20.0,
                  decoration:
                      BoxDecoration(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0)),
                  child: (const Text(
                    'Hello',
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.black),
                  )),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 300.0, top: 1.0),
              child: IconButton(
                icon: const Icon(Icons.account_circle, size: 30.0),
                onPressed: () {
                  print("hit");
                  // Navigator.push(
                  //   context,
                  //   MaterialPageRoute(
                  //     builder: (context) => Notifications(),
                  //   ),
                  // );
                },
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 300.0, top: 5.0),
              child: IconButton(
                icon: const Icon(
                  Icons.notifications,
                  size: 25.0,
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  print("hit ");
                  // Navigator.push(
                  //   context,
                  //   MaterialPageRoute(
                  //     builder: (context) => Notifications(),
                  //   ),
                  // );
                },
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 0.0),
              child: Center(
                child: Container(
                  width: 390,
                  height: 450,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.green.shade100,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(onPressed: () async {
        // await authService.signOut();
      }),
    ),
    const Text(
      'Index 1: Business',
    ),
    const Text(
      'Index 2: School',
    ),
  ];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: _widgetOptions.elementAt(_selectedIndex),
      ),

      //  : _children[_currentIndex],
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        backgroundColor: Colors.green[100],
        items: const [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.book_online),
            label: 'Page 1',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.read_more),
            label: 'Page 2',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.account_circle),
            label: 'Profile',
          ),
        ],
        currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
        selectedItemColor: Colors.amber[800],
        onTap: _onItemTapped,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Output**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi, what i want to is to navigate to a different screen using the bottom navigation bar.

Comment: Yes you can do that just change the screen on ontap function

Comment: I tried it, but i get this error : 

The argument type 'void Function()' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(int)?'.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `onTap: onTabTapped` on your `BottomNavigationBar`, then navigate to your destination page using selected index

```
  void onTabTapped(int index) {
    if(index==2) {
      Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
        new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => new YourPage())
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to below code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> _navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
  int _currentTabIndex = 0;
  ValueNotifier<bool> refreshPage = ValueNotifier(false);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ValueListenableBuilder<bool>(
      valueListenable: refreshPage,
      builder: (context, value, child) {
        return WillPopScope(
          onWillPop: () {
            Navigator.of(context).pop();
          },
          child: Scaffold(
            backgroundColor: _currentTabIndex == 0
                ? Colors.white
                : _currentTabIndex == 1
                    ? Colors.green
                    : Colors.green,
            appBar: AppBar(
              backgroundColor: Colors.white,
              elevation: 0,
              title: Text(
                "Bottom Navigation Bar",
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.black,
                    fontSize: 14,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
              ),
              leading: IconButton(
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.arrow_back_ios,
                  size: 18.0,
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                },
              ),
              centerTitle: true,
            ),
            body: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: _currentTabIndex == 0
                  ? Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 80.0, right: 250),
                          child: Center(
                            child: Container(
                              width: 200.0,
                              height: 20.0,
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0)),
                              child: (const Text(
                                'Hello',
                                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                    color: Colors.black),
                              )),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 300.0, top: 1.0),
                          child: IconButton(
                            icon: new Icon(Icons.account_circle, size: 30.0),
                            onPressed: () {
                              Navigator.push(
                                context,
                                MaterialPageRoute(
                                  builder: (context) => Notifications(),
                                ),
                              );
                            },
                          ),
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 300.0, top: 5.0),
                          child: IconButton(
                            icon: const Icon(
                              Icons.notifications,
                              size: 25.0,
                            ),
                            onPressed: () {
                              Navigator.push(
                                context,
                                MaterialPageRoute(
                                  builder: (context) => Notifications(),
                                ),
                              );
                            },
                          ),
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 0.0),
                          child: Center(
                            child: Container(
                              width: 390,
                              height: 450,
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  color: Colors.green.shade100,
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    )
                  : _currentTabIndex == 1
                      ? Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: [
                            Container(
                                color: Colors.green,
                                child: Center(child: Text("Page 2"))),
                          ],
                        )
                      : Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: [
                            Container(
                                color: Colors.green,
                                child: Center(child: Text("Profile"))),
                          ],
                        ),
            ),
            bottomNavigationBar: _bottomNavigationBar(),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  Widget _bottomNavigationBar() {
    return BottomNavigationBar(
      type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
      items: [
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.book_online),
          label: 'Page 1',
        ),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.read_more),
          label: 'Page 2',
        ),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.account_circle),
          label: 'Profile',
        )
      ],
      onTap: _onTap,
      currentIndex: _currentTabIndex,
    );
  }

  _onTap(int tabIndex) {
    switch (tabIndex) {
      case 0:
        Notifications();
        // _navigatorKey.currentState.pushReplacementNamed("Page 1");
        break;
      case 1:
        Notifications();
        //  _navigatorKey.currentState.pushReplacementNamed("Page 2");
        break;
      case 2:
        Notifications();
        // _navigatorKey.currentState.pushReplacementNamed("Profile");
        break;
    }

    _currentTabIndex = tabIndex;
    refreshPage.value = !refreshPage.value;
  }

  Route<dynamic> generateRoute(RouteSettings settings) {
    switch (settings.name) {
      case "Page 1":
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Notifications()
            // Container(
            //     color: Colors.green, child: Center(child: Text("Page 1")))
            );
      case "Page 2":
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Notifications()
            //  Container(
            //     color: Colors.green, child: Center(child: Text("Page 2")))
            );
      default:
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Notifications()
            // Container(
            //     color: Colors.green, child: Center(child: Text("Profile")))
            );
    }
  }
}

class Notifications extends StatefulWidget {
  Notifications({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _NavitionState createState() => _NavitionState();
}

class _NavitionState extends State<Notifications> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () {
        Navigator.of(context).pop();
      },
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          elevation: 0,
          title: Text(
            "Notification",
            style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.black, fontSize: 14, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
          ),
          leading: IconButton(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.arrow_back_ios,
              size: 18.0,
              color: Colors.black,
            ),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
            },
          ),
          centerTitle: true,
        ),
        body: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Center(
              child: Container(
                child: Text("Notification Body"),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```